# Python GTK MVC: Kiwi?

Tags: python, model-view-controller, gtk

I've been looking around for a good MVC framework for Python using PyGTK. I've looked at [Kiwi](http://www.async.com.br/projects/kiwi/) but found it a bit lacking, especially with using the Gazpacho Glade-replacement.

Are there any other nice desktop Python MVC frameworks?  I'm one of the few (it seems) to not want a webapp.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93930/what-python-gui-apis-are-out-there, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35922/are-there-any-nice-to-program-gui-toolkits-for-python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In defense of Kiwi:

- Kiwi works fine with Glade3 instead of Gazpacho. (who forced you to use Gazpacho?)
- Kiwi is my first dependency for *any* PyGTK application commercial or open source.
- Kiwi is very actively maintained.

I have generally got to a stage where I think its irresponsible to not use Kiwi in a PyGTK application. Perhaps you can tell us what you found "lacking" so we can improve the framework. #kiwi on irc.gimp.net (or the Kiwi mailing list).

Comment: I was following the Kiwi tutorial and it used Gazpacho. When I tried to open up the example Glade files in Glade3 it didn't work so well. I didn't know that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There's [Dabo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310856/python-gtk-mvc), made by some guys moving from FoxPro.  It might work for you if you're writing a data driven business app.

Beyond that, I haven't found anything that you haven't.

> GUI stuff is *supposed* to be hard. It builds character.

([Attributed](http://quotations.amk.ca/python-quotes/#q28) to Jim Ahlstrom, at one of the early Python workshops.  Unfortunately, things haven't changed much since then.)

Answer (score 2):

"mvc" titled app:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/pygtkmvc/

"avc" titled app:

http://avc.inrim.it/html/

more information:

http://www.pygtk.org/applications.html

Answer (score 0):

PureMVC

http://trac.puremvc.org/PureMVC_Python